# Php and a dynamic loop for inserting into sql, both placement and variable must be dynamic

Tags: php, sql, loops, dynamic, insert

The vars are `$ingval1` and so on.. the SQL fields are the same, obviously without the $..

This section of my script is not updating the table, why?

```
     <?php // post

     $basename1 = 'ingval';$basename2 = 'ingamt';
     $basename3 = 'ingdes';$basename4 = 'ingcode';

     for ($y = 1; $y < 26; $y++) { 
         $tempname1 = $basename1 . $y; $tempname2 = $basename2 . $y; 
         $tempname3 = $basename3 . $y; $tempname4 = $basename4 . $y;  
         $$tempname1 = $_POST['ingval'.$y];
         $$tempname2 = $_POST['ingamt'.$y];
         $$tempname3 = $_POST['ingdes'.$y];
         $$tempname4 = $_POST['ingcode'.$y];


    }       // sql insert


    $basename1 = 'ingval';$basename2 = 'ingamt';
    $basename3 = 'ingdes';$basename4 = 'ingcode';

    for ($y = 1; $y < 26; $y++) { 

        $tempname1 = $basename1 . $y; $tempname2 = $basename2 . $y; 
        $tempname3 = $basename3 . $y; $tempname4 = $basename4 . $y; 

        $sql = "UPDATE $cookbookdb SET  

           ingval.$y = '" . $$tempname1 . "',
           ingamt.$y = '" . $$tempname2 . "',
           ingdes.$y = '" . $$tempname3 . "',
           ingcode.$y = '" . $$tempname4 . "'


        WHERE id = '" . $barcodeinput . "'";

        sql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

    } ?>
```

I've tried this a few different ways and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in the update statement? It might be valid, but I cannot see any values from your code that would make it valid.

Should it be :

```
ingval.$y = '" . $tempname1 . "'
```

instead in your update statement?

From the code, the value of `$tempname1` would be `ingval1` through `ingval26` but the value of `$$tempname1` would be the value of the variable called `$ingval1` through `$ingval26` which I cannot see in the code at all.

Comment: The data is coming from $_POST in earlier code, also with the same dynamic loop.

Comment: @MarkNelson Fair enough. Are you sure you aren't simply getting a blank variable being passed then? Have you echo'ed out the SQL query just prior to running it?

Comment: I'll have to do that, I'm kinda avoiding it because it's an already working software and it's a mess :). I'm just simply trying to make it more dynamic for future expansion and clean it up as I go. But in a nutshell are you saying it should be working?

Comment: @MarkNelson I can't see any reason that it should update a row. The SQL looks fine, I thought it was simply a syntax error, but you have that covered off well enough. The only thing that pops to mind is the old *is there a missing variable in the SQL* :) Just pop in a `echo $sql;` prior to the `sql_query` and see what it comes up with.

Comment: Both var_dump and echo come up blank in the loop, out of the loop I get results that look promising. Now I'm super confused :)

Comment: @MarkNelson That code has me a little puzzled, why are there two loops in there? It seems like it should be only one loop and there probably isn't a need for all the variable variable bits (unless they are used somewhere outside the code you have posted here).

Comment: Ok, strangely enough now its echoing. maybe an issue with my host for that one. But I did get it working after it started echoing, it was the 'ingval.$y', no need for the period 'ingval$y'.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, That is a long story.. I'm moving everything into classes and functions. Like I said it is a mess :P

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have connected to the database.

```
 mysql_connect('host','username','password');
 mysql_select_db('db');
```

if so what does the           `mysql_error()` say?

Comment: Yes, It has something to do with the loop. I'm kinda new to php, but I do have the basics down. I'm getting roughed up by this dynamic stuff. I also do not get an sql error

Comment: just copy paste the error you are receving in your question.that way we may be of more help to you